# Battery life Macbook 13 Retina mid 2014

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, memory

I got a new MBP 13 Retina display, mid 2014. I get on the battery up to 5 hours at most. Is this normal? This is my first product from Apple so I do not know if this is as supposed or I got the wrong idea.

**Configuration**

i5 2.6Ghz
16Gb Ram
256Gb SSD

The tools I mostly use are iTerm, Virtualbox, Spotify, browsing and some editor. How long should I get according to this workload?

Answer (score 1):

Battery life is heavily dependent upon how you use the system. Things such as leaving screen brightness at maximum can have significant effect on how quickly power is drained from a charged battery. Applications such as running guest operating systems inside of a virtual machine can be I/O- and CPU-intensive tasks that will also reduce the longevity of a charge.

If you're running VMs with regular screen brightness, I'd say 5 hours of battery is about right.

Comment: Actually I have the screen very low, like 20%. I don't either use the backlight. Right now after 20min running, it started 100% and it says now 99% 6h37min. But probably it will not take that long. I'm just worried if this is the case the battery is faulty, that it might be, why not? In any case, thanks for your answer.